# Convolving the relation $o(x)$

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, mobius-function

I'll get right to the point.  For sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ in $\mathbf C$, let $c_n = \sum_{d \mid n} a_db_{n/d}$. Set $A(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} a_n$, $B(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} b_n$, and $C(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} c_n$. If $A(x) = o(x)$ and $B(x) = o(x)$, must it be true that $C(x) = o(x)$, or is there a (simple) counterexample? And if there is a counterexample, is the conclusion valid if we also assume $A(x)$ or $B(x)$ is $O_\delta(x^{1-\delta})$ for some $\delta$ in $(0,1)$ but introduce no further assumptions?

This question came up when editing some course notes. When proving various relations are equivalent to the prime number theorem, the proof that $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = o(x)$ implies $\psi(x) \sim x$ appears to be basically the same everywhere I have looked and I'd prefer if there were a different argument. In the standard proof (whose basic structure goes back to [Landau](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015073682109&view=1up&seq=1005) (see Section 1)), you reduce the problem to checking that
$$
\sum_{dd' \leq x} \mu(d)(\log(d') - \tau(d') + 2\gamma) = o(x),
$$
where $\tau(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} d$ and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. The proof of this $o(x)$ estimate uses the following three properties:

1. $\sum_{n \leq x} \mu(n) = o(x)$,
2. $\sum_{n \leq x} (\log(n) - \tau(n) + 2\gamma) = O(\sqrt{x})$,
3. $|\mu(n)| \leq 1$ for all $a$.

Abstracting what makes the proof work, we can say for my question at the start that $A(x) = o(x)$ and $B(x) = o(x)$ implies $C(x) = o(x)$ if we add the conditions that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded (think $a_n = \mu(n)$) and $B(x) = O_\delta(x^{1-\delta})$ for some $\delta$ in $(0,1)$ (think $b_n = \log(n) - \tau(n) + 2\gamma$ and $\delta = 1/2$). I would prefer a proof of $C(x) = o(x)$ that is more symmetric in the assumptions on $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ while still being applicable to the intended example above ($a_n = \mu(n)$ and $b_n = \log n - \tau(n) + 2\gamma$).

I have not seen a result of the form "$A(x) = o(x)$ and $B(x) = o(x)$ implies $C(x) = o(x)$" anywhere, so I suspect it might not be true, but I have not seen (or created) a counterexample either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the simple counterexample:

Take $f$ increasing to $\infty$ such that $\tau(n)>f(n)$ for a positive proportion of integers.

($f(n)=\log\log(n+2)$ should work).

Let $$a(n)=b(n)= \frac1{\sqrt{f(n)}},\qquad a(d)b(n/d)\ge a(n)b(n)=\frac1{f(n)}$$

$a(n)=b(n)=o(1)$ so $A(n)=B(n)=o(n)$ but $$c(n)\ge \frac{\tau(n)}{f(n)}\ge 1$$ for a positive proportion of integers, therefore $C(n)\ne o(n)$.

Comment: Ok. Did you pick $\log\log(n+2)$ from the Hardy-Ramanujan theorem? Put $\varepsilon = 1/3$ in that to get almost all positive integers $n$ satisfy $\omega(n) > \log\log n - (\log \log n)^{5/6} > (\log\log n)/10$, where last inequality holds if $y := \log\log n$ fits $y - y^{5/6} > y/10$, i.e., $y > (10/9)^6 = 1.88\ldots$, i.e., $n > \exp(\exp((10/9)^6)) \approx 709.45$. So for almost all $n$, $\omega(n) > (\log\log n)/10$, hence $\tau(n) \geq 2^{\omega(n)} > (\log n)^{(\log 2)/10} = (\log n)^{.0693\ldots}$. So we can use $f(n) = (\log n)^{.06}$ in your counterexample.

Comment: Some $f$ exists because $\lim_{s\to 1} \frac{\sum_n n^{-s}/\tau(n)}{\sum_n n^{-s}}\ll \lim_{s\to 1} \prod_p (1-p^{-s}/2)=0$